# Identify TVS: SMC package, GEM 88A

Tags: identification, tvs

I have this TVS installed on some CCAs.  It is not marked like the correct part.  The correct part is marked GEM 15A as opposed to this part which is marked GEM 88A.

[image: Picture of TVS on CCA]

Comment: Are you saying this device is not working correctly due to a wrong part? If so what is the problem?

Comment: I got this passed to me from the technician.  I did not get a specific fault description.  I did ask for that and have not heard back yet.  I just got his not stating that some CCA have failed and on each one that failed the part was marked 88A as opposed to 15A.  The correct part is the 15V TVS as was mentioned in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

This part appears to be standardized, meaning a lot of manufacturers have made this single part.

Google searching, "GEM TVS Datasheet", has led me to this page: https://www.alldatasheet.net/view_marking.jsp?Searchword=GEM

Choosing one of the manufacturers and scrolling down in the datasheet will show a list of markings and the appropriate part number.

See below as an example of one datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view-marking/1037218/SUNMATE/SMC8.0.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The logo is General Semiconductor, a Vishay brand.  The package looks to be SMC (but, a dimensional reference would be helpful).

This suggests 1.5SMC TransZorb series: https://www.vishay.com/docs/88303/15smc.pdf

`15A` appears to be the standard marking for a 15V unidirectional part.  Other than the polarity mark, other package markings are not indicated, not even the logo.  It is possible they use `GEM` as an additional marking, but the datasheet does not require it.

`88A` doesn't seem to be a valid part, or a standard one.  It's possible it's a poorly rendered "68"; it is difficult to take good photos of semiconductor markings, unfortunately.

[Colin's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/706689/311631) suggests `GEM` is a standard marking used by other manufacturers; it would be quite convenient if the manufacturer in fact provides both marking schemes.  (It would be even more convenient if they documented that fact..!)

---

In fact they do!  Just not in the datasheet.  Well, and they don't, but it's more interesting how!

Thanks to vivier in a comment: 
https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf 
This device appears to be defined at the top of page 4; it seems it's pure chance that one series has a common naming scheme.  Then, it must be the "15A" and "88A" are year ending in digits -1 and -8, months May and August, and optional factory 'A'.

No format supports the interpretation as 1.5SMC series, and there is no double type marking listed.  (The 3rd one down is closest, but the note explains it's for long part numbers, not a cross-reference.)

It must then be the (de facto?) industry standard SMCJ series, which Vishay/GS does indeed offer: 
https://www.vishay.com/docs/88394/smcj.pdf 
We can confidently conclude your parts are correct, and the 15A/88A code is simply date and factory.

---

Interestingly, if I had come across Vishay/GS SMCJ initially, I'd probably have come to the same conclusion as Colin; this series has much lower PageRank than Littelfuse, ST and etc.'s do, and the 1.5SMC series showed up in search results far before Vishay SMCJ did.  (It doesn't even appear in their own product listing until further down; at least, the way I explored it.)  The one hint along the way was the "88A" not being a standard part, but in lieu of further information, it seems as plausible as anything else.

I could edit this post to resolve the two above sections, but it seems more interesting to show the process, and how one can easily find coincidences and sidetracks when identifying parts.

I'm reminded of the occasion I was flipping through some drawers of old components, and happened across a few 7406 hex inverters from the 4th week of 1974; or was it 7404s from the 6th week?.. (No, no manufacturer prefix or logo, just a pair of coincidental numbers on an early plastic DIP package.)

Comment: it is documented. https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf